# return new futureBuilder keeps requesting to the server on screen size change

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm building an app which has a bottomBar that request data from the server, and when I change the size of the screen it request again to the server

this is my bottomBar Widget

```
Widget bottomNavigationBar() {
  return new BottomAppBar(
    color: const Color(0xFF1E90FF),
    child: new Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
      children:[
        Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20),
          child: futureBuilderWidget(setVersion())
        ),
        Container(
          child: Text(
              DateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss').format(DateTime.now()),
              style: TextStyle( fontSize: 16, color: const Color(0xffebebeb))
          ),
        ),
       
      ],
    ),
  );
}
```

And this is my futureBuilder widget

```
  Widget futureBuilderWidget(_future) {
    return new FutureBuilder<dynamic>(
      future: _future,
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<dynamic> snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
          if (snapshot.hasError) {
            return Text(
              snapshot.error.toString(),
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16, color: const Color(0xffebebeb)),
            );
          } else if (snapshot.hasData) {
            return Text(snapshot.data,
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16, color: const Color(0xffebebeb)),
            );
          }
        }
        return CircularProgressIndicator();
      },
    );
  }
```

Is there anyway in which I could just ask once?

Comment: Have you tried to use a bool value, so you can verify and store that the bottomBar has been loaded?

Comment: yes, i tried but i broke the bottomBar it went to full screen and didnt show anything

Comment: Ok, but you can also store the data from the server while launching the app.

Answer (score 0):

Place future inside init() state. It will run only once I hope. PS: Don't put it in setState() it will run every time your screen regenerates.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that the `_future` contains an HTTP request. As mentioned in the [`FutureBuilder`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html) docs, `future` should be obtained earlier.

> The future must have been obtained earlier, e.g. during State.initState, State.didUpdateWidget, or State.didChangeDependencies. It must not be created during the State.build or StatelessWidget.build method call when constructing the FutureBuilder. If the future is created at the same time as the FutureBuilder, then every time the FutureBuilder's parent is rebuilt, the asynchronous task will be restarted.

What you can do here is either run the request on `initState()` and update `Future<dynamic> _future` with a `setState()` to trigger a widget rebuild, or use [`async`](https://pub.dev/packages/async) package to only run the request once.

```dart
final AsyncMemoizer _memoizer = AsyncMemoizer();

Future<dynamic> _future() {
  return _memoizer.runOnce(() async {
    // Do the request
  });
}
```